# Mapping object key values in dictionary and mapping properties with JsonPropertyName

Tags: c#, json.net, webclient

I created a basic console app that calls an external API. My Main method is hard coded for testing purpose:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // building a login request
    LoginRequest loginRequest = new LoginRequest("myLogin", "myPassword");
    LoginService loginService = new LoginServiceImpl();

    LoginResponse loginResponse = loginService.Authenticate(loginRequest);
        
    Console.WriteLine("Authentication tryout!");
    Console.WriteLine(">> Token : " + loginResponse.AccessToken);
    Console.WriteLine(">> Type  : " + loginResponse.TokenType);
}
```

I'm passing an object to the service layer. In this class I implemented the method Authenticate:

```
public LoginResponse Authenticate(LoginRequest request)
{
    LoginResponse returnValue = new  LoginResponse();
    Uri uri = new Uri("http://www.myapi.com/v1/login");
    HttpRequest httpRequest = new HttpRequest();   

    Task<LoginResponse> loginTask = httpRequest.Authentication(request, uri);
    returnValue = loginTask.GetAwaiter().GetResult();

    return returnValue;
}
```

Now here are my 2 problems while calling Authentication method in HttpRequest:

```
public async Task<LoginResponse> Authentication(LoginRequest request, Uri url)
{
    var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    dict.Add("login", request.login);
    dict.Add("password", request.Password);

    HttpClient client = new HttpClient(); 
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
        new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json")
    );
    var req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url) { 
        Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(dict) 
    }; 
    var response = await client.SendAsync(req); 
        
    string output = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(output));
    LoginResponse returnValue = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LoginResponse>(output);
        
    return returnValue;
 }
```

My first issue is that my dictionnary is duplicating the key values in the dictionary.
I have :

```
Key: "username"
value: "helloWorld"
Key: "username"
value: "helloWorld"
```

I also tried to use dictionnary with something like this :

```
var dictionary = ToDictionary<string>(request);
foreach(KeyValuePair<string, string> entry in dictionary)
{
    dictionary.Add(entry.Key, entry.Value);
    Console.WriteLine(entry.Key);
    Console.WriteLine(entry.Value);
}
```

The ToDictionnary is the following :

```
public Dictionary<string, TValue> ToDictionary<TValue>(object obj)
{       
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
    var dictionary = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, TValue>>(json);
    if (dictionary != null)
    {
        return dictionary;
    }
    // handle exception here... 
    return null;
}
```

It also duplicated the key value and throws an exception.

My Second issue is that I don't know how to map JsonPropertyName with the Property name.
My call returns a string that i convert to object.

My model is the following:

```
public class LoginResponse
{
    [JsonPropertyName("access_token")]
    public string AccessToken { get; set; }
    
    [JsonPropertyName("type_token")]
    public string TokenType { get; set; }

    public LoginResponse() { }
}
```

As a result I do get a string that i map as object but keys are not mapped:
I obtain :

```
{ "access_token": "abcdef", "type_token": "Bearer" }
```

While I expect :

```
{ "AccessToken": "abcdef", "TokenType": "Bearer" }
```

Comment: You want to ask one question at a time, not two questions at once.

Comment: Could you please provide a [mre] for each individual question?

Comment: If you write `[JsonPropertyName("access_token")]`, why do you expect `"AccessToken": "abcdef"`?

Comment: access_token is what I receive and my model is following member naming convention : AccessToken. my issue was to map both when I was deserializing the object. I was not using the right library in my model.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue with serialization. I was using System.Text.Json.Serialization...
I replaced by using Newtonsoft.Json in my model.

I also changed annotation:

```
[JsonPropertyName("access_token")]
```

with :

```
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "access_token")]
```